# JNA link failure Error on Cassandra Startup

Tags: cassandra, jna

I am am trying to run Cassandra instance through eclipse on Windows.

In Eclipse run configuration I have specified org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon class and in VM arguments I have specified below mentioned VM arguments :

-Dcassandra.config=file:C:\nw_servers\apache-cassandra-2.1.3\conf\cassandra.yaml
-Dcassandra-foreground 
-ea -Xmx1G
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:\nw_servers\apache-cassandra-2.1.3\conf\log4j-server.properties

When I run the CassandraDaemon class in eclipse i get below mentioned error.

WARN  02:23:07 JNA link failure, one or more native method will be unavailable.
WARN  02:23:07 JNA link failure, one or more native method will be unavailable.

Comment: Cassandra usage of JNA is optional.  Do you get this warning when you run Cassandra outside of Eclipse?

Comment: I have not tried outside eclipse, but what needs to be done to fix it inside eclipse

Comment: I'll be easier to get it to run *outside* of eclipse, and once you've determined what settings you need to enable in that case, you can apply them to the appropriate areas of your eclipse setup.  At a minimum, in either case you're going to need to ensure that jna.jar is available in your runtime classpath.