# JNA link failure Error on Cassandra Startup on OS X

Tags: cassandra

*Note: I know that here is same question, but it's enviroment is window so I created it. [JNA link failure Error on Cassandra Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000915/jna-link-failure-error-on-cassandra-startup)*

I try to start cassandra but I get a warning below:

```
$ cassandra
...
WARN  09:13:42 JNA link failure, one or more native method will be unavailable.
WARN  09:13:42 JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

My enviroment:

- Cassandra v2.2.0 with Homebrew
- OS X 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNA is used for optimizations such as disabling swapping and creating hardlinks during snapshots. It is recommended for production systems. Dev systems should also be fine without JNA support, so you can just ignore the warning.